Difference between 織物, 生地 and 布
As the title says, what are the differences/usages of 織物, 生地 and 布?
I can't figure out anything obvious from the Weblio definitions or from a Google image search. If you were to ask me the difference between 'material', 'fabric' and 'cloth' I'm not sure I could provide a convincing answer. I wonder if it's the same here?

生地 generally refers to any plain surface with uniform material/texture, where you may also find it often used for "dough".

布 refers to cloth or fabric in general, without specifying its construction, use, or quality. It's a broad term that can refer to rags, wiping cloths, or the material used for expensive dresses.
生地 specifically refers to the fabric used for making garments or curtains. It emphasizes the state or quality of the fabric before it is transformed into a finished product. It's typically used in the context of "what this dress/hat/etc is made of". It's used like "良い生地のTシャツは長持ちする", "スーツは生地によって涼しさが違う", etc.
織物 refers to traditional fabrics or textiles that are (usually manually) woven using a loom and possess aesthetic quality on their own. They usually feature characteristic patterns. Japanese 織物 are typically used to make kimonos (e.g., 西陣織), but pieces of 織物 are also sold at souvenir shops worldwide in the form of handkerchiefs, tapestries or rugs.

+1. One can perhaps get a better idea of 織物 (google image search ) in comparison with, for example, 染物 (google image) where the patterns are dyed instead of woven.
